# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider $$rAFProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material, angularjs-module

Im getting [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=Hive&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.7%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngMaterial%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Amodulerr%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.7%252F%2524injector%252Fmodulerr%253Fp0%253Dmaterial.core%2526p1%253DError%25253A%252520%25255B%252524injector%25253Aunpr%25255D%252520http%25253A%25252F%25252Ferrors.angularjs.org%25252F1.2.7%25252F%252524injector%25252Funpr%25253Fp0%25253D%25252524%25252524rAFProvider%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520Error%252520(native)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fpreview.c9users.io%25252Famanuel2%25252Fhive%25252Fassets%25252Fdist%25252Fjs%25252Fvendor.min.js%25253A3%25253A3596%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fpreview.c9users.io%25252Famanuel2%25252Fhive%25252Fassets%25252Fdist%25252Fjs%25252Fvendor.min.js%25253A3%25253A16377%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520Object.n%252520%25255Bas%252520get%25255D%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fpreview.c9users.io%25252Famanuel2%25252Fhive%25252Fassets%25252Fdist%25252Fjs%25252Fvendor.min.js%25253A3%25253A15452)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520Object.decorator%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fpreview.c9users.io%25252Famanuel2%25252Fhive%25252Fassets%25252Fdist%25252Fjs%25252Fvendor.min.js%25253A3%25253A16244)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520n%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fpreview.c9users.io%25252Famanuel2%25252Fhive%25252Fassets%25252Fdist%25252Fjs%25252Fvendor.min.js%25253A6%25253A8402)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520Object.r%252520%25255Bas%252520invoke%25255D%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fpreview.c9users.io%25252Famanuel2%25252Fhive%25252Fassets%25252Fdist%25252Fjs%25252Fvendor.min.js%25253A3%25253A15702)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fpreview.c9users.io%25252Famanuel2%25252Fhive%25252Fassets%25252Fdist%25252Fjs%25252Fvendor.min.js%25253A3%25253A15060%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520Array.forEach%252520(native)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520o%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fpreview.c9users.io%25252Famanuel2%25252Fhive%25252Fassets%25252Fdist%25252Fjs%25252Fvendor.min.js%25253A3%25253A3925)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fpreview.c9users.io%252Famanuel2%252Fhive%252Fassets%252Fdist%252Fjs%252Fvendor.min.js%253A3%253A3596%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fpreview.c9users.io%252Famanuel2%252Fhive%252Fassets%252Fdist%252Fjs%252Fvendor.min.js%253A3%253A15261%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Array.forEach%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520o%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fpreview.c9users.io%252Famanuel2%252Fhive%252Fassets%252Fdist%252Fjs%252Fvendor.min.js%253A3%253A3925)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520i%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fpreview.c9users.io%252Famanuel2%252Fhive%252Fassets%252Fdist%252Fjs%252Fvendor.min.js%253A3%253A14873)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fpreview.c9users.io%252Famanuel2%252Fhive%252Fassets%252Fdist%252Fjs%252Fvendor.min.js%253A3%253A14950%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Array.forEach%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520o%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fpreview.c9users.io%252Famanuel2%252Fhive%252Fassets%252Fdist%252Fjs%252Fvendor.min.js%253A3%253A3925)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520i%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fpreview.c9users.io%252Famanuel2%252Fhive%252Fassets%252Fdist%252Fjs%252Fvendor.min.js%253A3%253A14873)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fpreview.c9users.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js:3:3596%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fpreview.c9users.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js:3:15261%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20o%20(https:%2F%2Fpreview.c9users.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js:3:3925)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20i%20(https:%2F%2Fpreview.c9users.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js:3:14873)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fpreview.c9users.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js:3:14950%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20o%20(https:%2F%2Fpreview.c9users.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js:3:3925)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20i%20(https:%2F%2Fpreview.c9users.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js:3:14873) error.

As i keep clicking the links i get:

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module Hive due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)

to

Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=m...)

to

Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module material.core due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%2...

to

Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $$rAFProvider
```

Now here is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dist/css/vendor.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js"></script>






    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" type="text/css" />


    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>


</head>


    <body ng-app="Hive">


      <div ui-view class="main_view">
      </div>


   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-energized">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Discussions" icon="ion-android-contacts" ui-sref="discussions">
          <ion-nav-view name="discussions-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Board" icon="ion-ios-list-outline" ui-sref="board">
          <ion-nav-view name="list-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>


             <ion-tab title="Me" icon="ion-android-happy" ui-sref="me">
          <ion-nav-view name="profile-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>


  </body>


</html>
```

app.module.js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('Hive', [
            'ionic',
            'ui.router',
            'ngMaterial',
            'firebase',
            'ngMessages',
        ]
    );

})(angular);
```

and if your wondering what vendor.min.js is , its basically all the libs im about to show combined to one file minified:

```
 vendor_js: [
        'assets/lib/js/ionic/ionic.min.js',
        'assets/lib/js/angular/angular.min.js',
        'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
        'bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js',
        'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
        'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js',
        'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js',
        'assets/lib/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.min.js',
//        'assets/lib/js/ionic/ionic-angular.min.js',
       'assets/lib/js/firebase/firebase.js',
        'assets/lib/js/firebase/angularfire.min.js',
    ],
```

and if you are wondering what app.min.js is , its all the controllers ,services , etc...

Help would be greatly , greatly appreciated(as i was stuck on this problem for about 10 hours now... ) ! Thanks :)

Comment: Well, how many questions **about the same thing** do you want to create? Aren't **FOUR** questions enough?

Comment: I'm curious!  How your `vendor_js` files will be loaded ?

Comment: @developer033 i have been attacking this for too long , and im getting irritated sorry.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH , gulp. You can see here: (Web IDE) https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/hive

Comment: Certainly, your module fails to load because of missing dependencies! Please try to add all files in `vendor_js` directly in your page and see if the problem persists. Who knows! sometimes the minification process break things!